# How can a used alkaline cell rate at 1.9 volts?

Tags: batteries

Today I replaced the battery of four alkaline AAA cells in an LED bicycle lamp, which was connected in two parallel series of two cells**. The four old cells were installed new from the same pack and (unsurprisingly) look identical. The brand is Kodak Xtralife, and they are labelled as alkaline AAA LR03 1.5V. Their expiry date is marked as 09-2020.

I checked the voltage of the old cells: three measured at close to 1.32 V; but the fourth one was over 1.9 (sic) V. I tested the cells repeatedly, using three different makes of electronic multimeter, along with a new alkaline cell for comparison, which measured at 1.560, 1.570, and 1.576 volts on the three meters—absolutely normal figures as I would have expected from numerous such measurements in the past. The three meters were self-consistent in repeated measurements, with the low-reading meter reporting about 11 mV below the middle-reading meter, which in turn read below the high-reading meter, although in the latter case the differences between the two meters changed according to whether the measured voltage was 1.3 or 1.6 volts: respectively 2 and 6 millivolts.

While the three meters all reported initially above 1.9 volts for the fourth cell, I am finding that, with repeated measurements, the voltage is dropping on this cell, and it is now 1.879, 1.893, and 1.898 volts according to them.

New alkaline cells always test at about 1.57 V, the voltage declining with use. So how can a used cell test at 1.9 volts?

**This turned out to be wrong: the cells were actually in a single series of four.

Comment: Are you sure its alkaline and not lithium?

Comment: @PlasmaHH: Pretty sure. See the further details added in the first paragraph. Incidentally, I have never come across a AAA lithium cell—let alone one in a pack of (perfectly normal) alkaline cells.

Comment: Well, you can get almost every technology in every package. R03 formfactor doesn't dictate the chemistry. Anyways if you are absolutely sure they are identical, have looked at their label and they say its alkaline, load it down and see if it goes to an expected 1.6Vish, if yes, then you managed to put it in there in a way that it got charged (given that we have no idea how the batteries are arranged in that light, we can't tell how it might have been, maybe the two parallels of two series wasn't quite right)

Comment: Thank you, @PlasmaHH, for this helpful comment. I will do some more tests.

Comment: The parallel connection is very unusual, but raises some mutual (over) charging possibilities - perhaps one cell ended up with a low voltage, and its series partner was overcharged by the parallel pair.  But still seems odd.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: Your comment is highly relevant, given that the cells were actually in one series.

Answer (score 4):

Battery tests are generally done under a light load. If your meters are 10MOhm and the measurement affects the battery, it will likely drop much more notably with a 1kOhm resistor attached (which is only 1.9mA assuming 1.9V), let alone 100 Ohm.

If you want to use voltage as an indicator for battery condition you need to make sure you have a small current loading them, or the measurement has much less meaning than you think.

However, it is peculiar, regardless for an alkaline 1.5V-rated battery to become 1.9V. It is possible to get them to that voltage, so long as they are not 100% empty, for a short while (range of seconds to minutes, maybe a bit longer) without physical damage.
But it takes care and attention, which is unlikely to have been applied in this case in an inadvertent manner.

There may have been something strange going on in your device, which may have done something silly to the weakest battery in the whole chain. But if it stays above 1.6V even with 100 Ohm loading, I'm betting it is in fact not an actual Alkaline cell, as Plasma hinted at in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Alkaline batteries are prone to leaking potassium hydroxide.

It can be assumed that as a result of leakage, the contact of the alkaline cell is contaminated.

During measurement, a galvanic pair is created between the contact of the alkaline cell and the multimeter probe. Potassium hydroxide acts as an electrolyte.

The measured value consists of the voltage of the cell and the voltage between the contacts.

If there are noticeable leaks, be careful. A caustic agent can cause respiratory, eye and skin irritation.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an original answer, but rather an assembly of the answer by @Asmyldof, the comments by PlasmaHH and Chris Stratton, and a correction of a wrong assumption in my question. The cells were actually in a series of four. Probably what happened was that one cell was installed backwards. There was enough voltage in the remaining cells to overcome the opposite voltage in the wrongly installed cell and still operate the lamp. By chance, the operating conditions boosted the odd cell to 1.9 V, a temporary over-voltage that soon declined even on a light load. Thank you to everyone for solving the mystery.